# How to open scripts from Second Life viewer into console vim

Tags: command-line, gui, vim, gvim

I want everything that has to do with text to be edited within console `vim` with tabs.

My problem is that I can't open files in console `vim` from GUI, I can only open them in `gvim`. 
Does anyone know how I can do such a thing?

For example my most frequent issue is with a game called `Second Life`. In this game you can write scripts and it gives you the option to edit your scripts in External editors. 
I want my external editor to be console `vim`. These are the instructions from the game: 
`ExternalEditor: Path to program used to edit LSL scripts and XUI files, e.g.: /usr/bin/gedit --new-window "%s".` so when I put: `"/usr/bin/X11/gvim" "%s"` it works for gvim, but it opens a new one each time I edit a new script AND this doesn't work at all for console `vim`. I tried `vim` server, but it was a failure.

If someone knows how to do what I want, please share.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I guess the instructions that I read for `vim server` were not accurate. After digging a bit more into it, I found a line that works. 
I Initialized a vim server with the following command in terminal:

`vim --servername LSLEditor`

And then in the `Second Life` viewer external editor text I put:

`/usr/bin/X11/vim --servername LSLEditor --remote-tab "%s"`

Since this answer is more directed to `Second Life` I will Change the title so if someone else wants to do the same, they can find the answer here.